# Dual citizen entering Pakistan with expired Pakistani passport

Tags: customs-and-immigration, pakistani-citizens, pakistan

I am a dual citizen of USA and Pakistan.

I have a valid USA passport and expired Pakistani passport.

I will be traveling from USA to Pakistan.

I will be using my valid USA passport for travel.

Will my expired Pakistani passport be OK for entry into Pakistan? (I also have a valid CNIC card but it is not with me, is in Pakistan.)

Comment: Do you plan to enter Pakistan by land or by air?

Comment: This is old, I entered by air. I actually was able to enter after some trouble.

Comment: Could you add an answer describing your experience?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to enter after some hassle after showing pictures of my CNIC card. I wouldn't generally recommend it as I wasted a bunch of time.